# Can I go to another frame during an itemization with LaTeX Beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

Basically I want to do something like this:

```
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A \pause
    \item B \pause
    \item C \pause
    \showsubframe
    % continue here
    \item D \pause
    \item E \pause
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Subframe} % only show this during Frame 1, not also after
   % something to help explain point C from Frame 1
\end{frame}
```

Does anyone know how I can show one frame during another one? Also, I imagine I would have to define the subframe somewhere (for instance after the main frame) and I don't want to show it again after the main frame.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 14):

You can use `\againframe` to resume display of a former frame.

Example:

```
\frame<1-3>[frame1]{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> A
    \item<2-> B
    \item<3-> C
    \item<4-> D
    \item<5-> E
  \end{itemize}
}

\frame{
   % something to help explain point C from Frame 1
}

\againframe<4->{frame1}
```

Comment: I could not get the exact example to work. Changing the first line of the first frame to `\begin{frame}<1-3>[label=frame1]` (and the last to `\end{frame}`) did work.